# Is there any way to easily calculate misclassification rates from a prediction object with R?

Tags: r

I make a prediction from a model and a data frame in R like this

```
> prediction = predict (m, df)
```

That returns a factor variable that I can convert to row-vector dataframe. I can then merge that row-vector data frame with a row vector of the correct results and then manually calculate where the two data vectors diverge.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to go about this and you didn't provide too much information. Here are  a few quick examples of getting this kind of information:

```
> library(randomForest)
> data(imports85)
> model <- randomForest(bodyStyle~curbWeight+cityMpg ,data=imports85)
> 
> #contingency table
> (tab <- table(predict(model,imports85),imports85$bodyStyle))

              convertible hardtop hatchback sedan wagon
  convertible           6       0         0     0     0
  hardtop               0       7         0     0     0
  hatchback             0       1        63     4     3
  sedan                 0       0         7    92     1
  wagon                 0       0         0     0    21
> #error per class
> diag(prop.table(tab,1))
convertible     hardtop   hatchback       sedan       wagon 
  1.0000000   1.0000000   0.8873239   0.9200000   1.0000000 
> #overall error
> mean(predict(model,imports85) == imports85$bodyStyle)
[1] 0.9219512
```

Although I would generally recommend using something like `caret()` that can perform crossvalidation while training and supply you with those results.

Comment: in the table that you show, are the columns the predicted values and the rows the actual values, as in a confusion matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Comment: when using `table()` with two options the first input maps to rows and the second to columns, try out something like `table(1:5,6:10)` for this to be extra clear. So no, not in the example above but just switch the order if you'd like.